# Implementing "Zoom" feature in AVCamViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, zooming

I'm trying to implement "Zoom" feature in my app. My app only supports Still Image, no video capturing etc.. i thought it should be straight forward however, i'm able to zoom the image however when i take a stillImage, the image comes out as full image, no zoom-in/out effects. 
I'm using AVCamViewController class provided by Apple.
I would appreciate if you guys point what i'm missing.

```
- (IBAction)zoomView {
    self.zoomScale =  1 + self.zoomSlider.value;
    self.previewView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity,self.zoomScale, self.zoomScale);

    DLog(@"zoom scale:%f",self.zoomScale);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Apple's sample code, then I would suggest performing the zoom on the on the AVCaptureDeviceInput object as opposed to zooming a view.

For instance, this is how I do it within a UIGestureRecognizer (that handles pinch gestures):

```
dispatch_async(self.sessionQueue, ^{
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [[self getActiveVideoDeviceInput] device];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error])
    {
        device.videoZoomFactor = MAX(scale, 1.0);
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
});
```

Comment: @joelg, can you say why you suggest doing this over the view? You are correct that it seems to work (although sort of glitchy once you try to zoom after releasing the pinch), but I am curious why this is better than zooming the view? Thanks

Comment: Sure. Simply because the AVCaptureDevice documentation provides helpful descriptions of properties and methods to assist with zooming: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/videoZoomFactor